# error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const char [9], int)’

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a programme which aims to make a robot follow a ball. I used 18.04 Unbuntu. When I try to 'catkin_make', the error happened in ' vel_pub = nh.advertise("/cmd_vel", 30);
' (line 133). I dont know why and I am not familiar with ROS and C++.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static int iLowH = 10;
static int iHighH = 40;

static int iLowS = 90;
static int iHighS = 255;

static int iLowV = 1;
static int iHighV = 255;

geometry_msgs::Twist vel_cmd;   //speed message packet

ros::Publisher vel_pub;      //Velocity Post Object

void Cam_RGB_Callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
}

Mat imgOriginal = cv_ptr->image;

//Convert RGB image to HSV
Mat imgHSV;
vector<Mat> hsvSplit;
cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

//Do histogram equalization in HSV space
split(imgHSV, hsvSplit);
equalizeHist(hsvSplit[2],hsvSplit[2]);
merge(hsvSplit,imgHSV);
Mat imgThresholded;

//Binarize the image using the threshold ranges of Hue, Saturation and Value above
inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded);

//On operation (remove some noise)
Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(5, 5));
morphologyEx(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, MORPH_OPEN, element);

//Close operation (connect some connected domains)
morphologyEx(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, MORPH_CLOSE, element);

//Traverse the binarized image data
int nTargetX = 0;
int nTargetY = 0;
int nPixCount = 0;
int nImgWidth = imgThresholded.cols;
int nImgHeight = imgThresholded.rows;
int nImgChannels = imgThresholded.channels();
printf("horizontal width= %d   vertical height= %d\n",nImgWidth,nImgHeight);
for (int y = 0; y < nImgHeight; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < nImgWidth; x++)
    {
        if(imgThresholded.data[y*nImgWidth + x] == 255)
        {
            nTargetX += x;
            nTargetY += y;
            nPixCount ++;
        }
    }
}
if(nPixCount > 0)
{
    nTargetX /= nPixCount;
    nTargetY /= nPixCount;
    printf("Color centroid coordinates( %d , %d )  point= %d\n",nTargetX,nTargetY,nPixCount);
    //draw coordinates
    Point line_begin = Point(nTargetX-10,nTargetY);
    Point line_end = Point(nTargetX+10,nTargetY);
    line(imgOriginal,line_begin,line_end,Scalar(255,0,0),3);
    line_begin.x = nTargetX; line_begin.y = nTargetY-10;
    line_end.x = nTargetX; line_end.y = nTargetY+10;
    line(imgOriginal,line_begin,line_end,Scalar(255,0,0),3);
    //Calculate robot motion speed
    float fVelFoward = (nImgHeight/2-nTargetY)*0.002;     //Difference * Proportion
    float fVelTurn = (nImgWidth/2-nTargetX)*0.003;        //Difference * Proportion
    vel_cmd.linear.x = fVelFoward;
    vel_cmd.linear.y = 0;
    vel_cmd.linear.z = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.x = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.y = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.z = fVelTurn;
}
else
{
    printf("target color disappears...\n");
    vel_cmd.linear.x = 0;
    vel_cmd.linear.y = 0;
    vel_cmd.linear.z = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.x = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.y = 0;
    vel_cmd.angular.z = 0;
}

vel_pub.publish(vel_cmd);
printf("Robot movement speed( linear= %.2f , angular= %.2f )\n",vel_cmd.linear.x,vel_cmd.angular.z);

//Display processing results
imshow("RGB", imgOriginal);
imshow("Result", imgThresholded);
cv::waitKey(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "cv_image_node");
  
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber rgb_sub = nh.subscribe("/nao_robot/camera_bottom/image_raw", 1 , Cam_RGB_Callback);

vel_pub = nh.advertise("/cmd_vel", 30);

ros::Rate loop_rate(30);

//The window for generating image display and parameter adjustment is empty
namedWindow("Threshold", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Threshold", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Threshold", &iHighH, 179);

cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Threshold", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Threshold", &iHighS, 255);

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Threshold", &iLowV, 255); //Value (0 - 255)
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Threshold", &iHighV, 255);

    namedWindow("RGB");
    namedWindow("Result");
    while( ros::ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397598/error:-no-matching-function-for-call-to-%E2%80%98ros::nodehandle::advertise(const-char-%5B9%5D,-int)%E2%80%99/) by [doukione](https://answers.ros.org/users/99536/doukione/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the [roscpp overview on Publishers and Subscribers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) for example usage and API links. To me it looks like you are missing the required template parameter for the `ros::NodeHandle::advertise` method. You likely need to change the call to something like

```
vel_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 30);
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2022-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [doukione](https://answers.ros.org/users/99536/doukione/) on 2022-03-15**:
It worked! Thank you very much!!!